# How do you code a "Create" view for a model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `many-to-many` field in Menu model named `Roles`, i'm trying to create a 'create' view for the model.

my create action methods:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ParentMenuId = new SelectList(_db.Menus, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(_db.UserRoles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Menu menu)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)//the state is always **invalid**
        {
            _db.Menus.Add(menu);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ParentMenuId = new SelectList(_db.Menus, "Id", "Name", menu.ParentMenuId);
        return View(menu);
    }
```

my view(**Create.cshtml**):

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, "Roles")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("Roles")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles)
    </div>
```

how to fix it? I'm getting the following error:

`The ViewData item that has the key '' is of type '' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'`

Comment: Probably 'my view' - is your partial view, can you provide full code of your Create View?

Comment: @testCoder no, not  a partial view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error message is rather clear, you nead a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

So change your ViewBag.Roles definition from

```
new SelectList(_db.UserRoles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
```

to

```
_db.UserRoles.ToList().Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value=m.Id, Text=m.Name});
```

**Edit**

In your view :

```
@Html.ListBox("Roles", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles)
```

**Edit2**

You have a model binding problem

In your view

```
@Html.ListBox("selectedRoles", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles)
```

in your Post Action, try to add a new parameter :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Menu menu, int[] selectedRoles)
```

and treat each selected role "manually" in your action code.

**EDIT**

ViewModel sample (not working as is)
In your view, you need

- a DropDownList (ParentMenuId)
- a ListBox (RoleIDs)
- the result of this listBox (model binding for the post action)
- other properties of the Menu class (maybe not all)

The idea would be to create a

```
public class MenuViewModel 
{
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ParentMenuList {get;set;}//a dropDown
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList {get;set;}//a listBox
  public string Name {get;set;}//the menu name //the menu name
  public List<int> SelectedRoles {get;set;}
}
```

then your get Action would be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new MenuViewModel();
  model.ParentMenuList = new SelectList(_db.Menus, "Id", "Name");
  model.RoleList = new SelectList(_db.UserRoles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
  return View(model);
}
```

your view would have MenuViewModel... as model

```
@model MenuViewModel
//your other code
//the listbox
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedRoles, "Roles")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoles, Model.RoleList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles)
    </div>
```

then your POST action would become

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MenuViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var menu = new Menu {Name = model.Name };//for example
       menu.Roles =  _db.UserRoles.Where(rl => model.SelectedRoles.Contains(rl.Id)).ToList();
       _db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Pro ViewModel :

- you're just using the properties you need.
- you don't need ViewBag (which is nice to avoid : it's dynamic, not strongly typed, so... hard to test, refactoring problems, etc.)
- everything is in your view's model

Cons ViewModel :

- you have to map your Model to your ViewModel in the get action, and map from ViewModel to Model in post action, but... it's worse the price !

Comment: have u ever tried this? `_db.UserRoles.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value=m.Id, Name=m.Name});` obviously can't work

Comment: and still not work, the listBox show a list of '<select id="Roles" multiple="multiple" name="Roles" class="valid"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>
</select>'

Comment: not work, the Roles field in postback model is empty, error msg The value '1,3' is invalid.

Comment: @Kevin by the way, usage of a ViewModel would make things easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18722/discussion-between-kevin-and-raphael-althaus)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18730/discussion-between-raphael-althaus-and-kevin)

Answer (score -1):

I was create same project but i don't get that error.

It seems model of listbox was bound to another type, try to specify explicitly viewbag model like this:

```
@Html.ListBox("Roles",ViewBag.Roles as SelectList)
```

And in [HttpPost] method try to add ViewBag.Roles which exists in Create - get method, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Menu menu)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)//the state is always **invalid**
        {
            _db.Menus.Add(menu);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ParentMenuId = new SelectList(_db.Menus, "Id", "Name", menu.ParentMenuId);
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(_db.UserRoles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        return View(menu);
    }
```

Comment: the `Roles` field in postback model is empty, error msg `The value '1,3' is invalid.`.